# Why Presburger arithmetic cannot prove pigeonhole principle

Tags: logic, peano-axioms, provability, presburger-arithmetic

The *pigeonhole principle* is the scheme

$\forall \bar{a},s \{\forall x\!<\!s\!+\!1 \exists y\!<\!s\psi(x,y,\bar{a}) \to \exists x_1,x_2\!<\!s\!+\!1\exists y\!<\!s[x_1\neq x_2 \wedge \psi(x_1,y,\bar{a}) \wedge \psi(x_2,y,\bar{a})]\}$

for all formulas $\psi$. The scheme can be proved in Peano arithmetic using Gödel encoding of finite sequences and induction axioms. However, the scheme is multiplication-free so can also be perfectly stated in Presburger arithmetic. However, though Presburger arithmetic can prove all instances of the scheme (since its a decidable theory), it seems impossible for Presburger arithmetic to prove this scheme. Is there any deeper understanding of this phenomena?

Comment: What do you mean by "to prove this scheme"? A scheme is not a first order formula, so it cannot be "proved".

Comment: @Régis Scheme is like temporarily adding new predicates to the language. For instance, you can add a unary predicate "P" to the language and easily prove the theorem $\forall x P(x) \to \exists x P(x)$ using first-order logic. The theorem will always be true whenever "P" is substituted with a concrete formula.

Comment: @DieqiaoFeng Regis' point is, what do you mean by "prove this scheme" as opposed to "prove all instances of the scheme"? In particular, what *precisely* are you claiming that PA can prove, here? (One thing PA can prove is "PA proves all instances of the pigeonhole scheme," but this isn't even *expressible* in the language of Presburger arithmetic, so if this is what youo're asking about then it has a quite simple answer.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for the comment. What I mean is that PA proves all instances of the pigeonhole scheme and can also prove the scheme itself. On the contrary, Presburger arithmetic can prove all instances without multiplication, but can not prove the scheme. However, multiplication doesn't appear in the scheme. So my point is that why is multiplication necessary to prove this scheme.

Comment: Do you mean that PA can prove a "second-order" version of the scheme which instead of having a separate statement for each $\psi$, combines them all in a single statement where the role of $\psi$ has been replaced by a single variable that encodes a finite sequence which we can then quantify over?  In that case, again the point is just that Presburger arithmetic can't even express such a statement.

Comment: @DieqiaoFeng Again, **what does "prove the scheme itself" *mean***? I really don't understand what it is you're trying to say. Eric's reformulation is plausible, but you really need to state exactly what it is you mean by this.

Comment: @EricWofsey Proving the scheme means a first-order system can prove this sentence with a "predicate variable". For example, both PA and Presburger arithmetic can directly prove such schemes: $\forall x P(x) \to \exists x P(x)$ and $\exists x P(x) \to \exists y P(y) [\forall z < y \neg P(z)]$, without a specific instantiation of the predicate "P". The question is PA can prove the pigeonhole scheme while Presburger arithmetic can not. However, to state this scheme multiplication is not needed.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Proving the scheme means a first-order system can prove this sentence with a "predicate variable". For example, both PA and Presburger arithmetic can directly prove such schemes: $\forall x P(x) \to \exists x P(x)$ and $\exists x P(x) \to \exists y P(y) [\forall z < y \neg P(z)]$, without a specific instantiation of the predicate "P". The question is PA can prove the pigeonhole scheme while Presburger arithmetic can not. However, to state this scheme multiplication is not needed.

Comment: @DieqiaoFeng That's not true - neither PA nor Presburger can even *express* those statements, since they don't allow predicate variables or "undetermined unary predicate symbols." Second-order versions, or appropriate expansions to a larger language, can; but you still haven't defined precisely what it is you're talking about.

Comment: It seems like what you're actually doing is the following: you're expanding PA to a new theory, PA$^+$, with a new unary predicate symbol $U$ and an extended induction scheme to cover formulas containing $U$ *(if you don't extend the induction scheme this way, you can't even prove that if $U$ is closed under successor then $U$ is closed under addition!)*, and now proving "the pigeonhole statement for $U$" in PA$^+$. And you're asking whether the analogous theory, Presburger$^+$, proves the same statement. Is this correct?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ahhhh yes! Thanks for clarifying this for me. That’s exactly what I mean. Both PA and PresA can represent the pigeanhole principle but only PA can prove it. On the contrary, PresA is complete so it can actually prove all instances of the scheme. It is the point that I am begging for an answer.

Comment: @DieqiaoFeng Would you mind if I edited your question to take into account the comments above? I think this would improve it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you, that's will be very helpful. I am new to this community, so sometimes I can not answer and question formally...